# Interview question:How to get last 3 month aggregation at column level?

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

This is the question i was being asked at Apple onsite interview and it blew my mind. Data is like this:

```
orderdate,unit_of_phone_sale

20190806,3000

20190704,3789

20190627,789

20190503,666

20190402,765
```

I had to write a query to get the result for each month sale, we should have last 3 month sales values. Let me put the expected output here.

```
order_monnth,M-1_Sale, M-2_Sale, M-3_Sale

201908,3000,3789,789,666

201907,3789,789,666,765

201906,789,666,765,0

201905,666,765,0,0

201904,765,0,0
```

I could only got the month wise sale and and used case statement by hardcoding month which was wrong. I banged my head to write this sql, but i could not.

Can anyone help on this. It will be really helpful for me to prepare for sql interviews

Update: This is what i tried

```
with abc as(
select to_char(order_date,'YYYYMM') as yearmonth,to_char(order_date,'YYYY') as year,to_char(order_date,'MM') as moth, sum(unit_of_phone_sale) as unit_sale
from t1 group by to_char(order_date,'YYYYMM'),to_char(order_date,'YYYY'),to_char(order_date,'MM'))
select yearmonth, year, case when month=01 then unit_sale else 0 end as M1_Sale,
case when month=02 then unit_sale else 0 end as M2_Sale...
case when month=12 then unit_sale else 0 end as M12_Sale
from abc
```

Comment: In an interview at Apple you have been asked a Oracle question? Is that really the expected output? I think this is too complex to be answered quickly in just one minute.

Comment: The first reply should be: "Never ever store **date** values as string or numbers - use proper `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data type."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will first of all need to sum the month's data and then use the LAG function to get previous months' data as following:

```
SELECT
    ORDER_MONTH,
    LAG(UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE, 1) OVER(
        ORDER BY
            ORDER_MONTH
    ) AS "M-1_Sale",
    LAG(UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE, 2) OVER(
        ORDER BY
            ORDER_MONTH
    ) AS "M-2_Sale",
    LAG(UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE, 3) OVER(
        ORDER BY
            ORDER_MONTH
    ) AS "M-3_Sale"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE, 'YYYYMM') AS ORDER_MONTH,
            SUM(UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE) AS UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE
        FROM
            DATAA
        GROUP BY
            TO_CHAR(ORDERDATE, 'YYYYMM')
    )
ORDER BY
    ORDER_MONTH DESC;
```

**Output:**

```
ORDER_   M-1_Sale   M-2_Sale   M-3_Sale
------ ---------- ---------- ----------
201908       3789        789        666
201907        789        666        765
201906        666        765
201905        765
201904
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f5f839d6730f209ff42560e4bb974873)

Cheers!!

**-- Update --**

For the requirement mentioned in the comments, Following query will work for it.

```
CTE AS (
    SELECT
        TRUNC(ORDERDATE, 'MONTH') AS ORDER_MONTH,
        SUM(UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE) AS UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE
    FROM
        DATAA
    GROUP BY
        TRUNC(ORDERDATE, 'MONTH')
)

SELECT
    TO_CHAR(C.ORDER_MONTH,'YYYYMM') as ORDER_MONTH,
    NVL(C1.UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE, 0) AS "M-1_Sale",
    NVL(C2.UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE, 0) AS "M-2_Sale",
    NVL(C3.UNIT_OF_PHONE_SALE, 0) AS "M-3_Sale"
FROM
    CTE C
    LEFT JOIN CTE C1 ON ( C1.ORDER_MONTH = ADD_MONTHS(C.ORDER_MONTH, - 1) )
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2 ON ( C2.ORDER_MONTH = ADD_MONTHS(C.ORDER_MONTH, - 2) )
    LEFT JOIN CTE C3 ON ( C3.ORDER_MONTH = ADD_MONTHS(C.ORDER_MONTH, - 3) )
ORDER BY
    C.ORDER_MONTH DESC
```

**Output:**

[image]

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2334314c8f5ce484ed39dd38b4ae483d) of updated answer.

Cheers!!

Comment: This is perfect

Comment: What if 201907 data is missing it wll take June as M-2 for the first record. Any idea how to solve it

Comment: Have you tried this query in mentioned situation? It will work exactly same way what you are expecting?

Comment: Sorry bad misunderstanding. What is your exact expectation?

Comment: so if data is missing for one month it should be null . eg for 201907 there are no data then for the row 201908 m_1_sale should be 0. could you please help

Comment: See my answer now (Update section)

Answer (score 0):

I think LEAD function can help here -

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(orderdate, 'YYYYMM') "DATE"
  ,unit_of_phone_sale M_1_Sale
  ,LEAD(unit_of_phone_sale,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY TO_CHAR(orderdate, 'YYYYMM') DESC) M_2_Sale
  ,LEAD(unit_of_phone_sale,2,0) OVER(ORDER BY TO_CHAR(orderdate, 'YYYYMM') DESC) M_3_Sale
  ,LEAD(unit_of_phone_sale,3,0) OVER(ORDER BY TO_CHAR(orderdate, 'YYYYMM') DESC) M_4_Sale
FROM table_sales
```

Here is the [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a71f789e63e6fa4dadd64074e0e790f8)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query:

```
select a.order_month, a.unit_of_phone_sale, 
LEAD(unit_of_phone_sale, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY rownum) AS M_1,
LEAD(unit_of_phone_sale, 2, 0) OVER (ORDER BY rownum) AS M_2,
LEAD(unit_of_phone_sale, 3, 0) OVER (ORDER BY rownum) AS M_3
from (
select TO_CHAR(orderdate, 'YYYYMM') order_month,
unit_of_phone_sale,
rownum
from Y
order by order_month desc) a
```

[image: Output]